# Understanding statistical independence of events using a relative frequency interpretation

Tags: probability, independence

This is what I've read in my textbook:

"If $n_A$ and $n_B$ are the number of times the independent events $A$ and $B$ have occurred, then we expect that the ratio $\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}$ (num. of times the intersection occurs over times $A$ occurs) also tends to $P(B)$" !!

I really don't understand how the author came to this conclusion! Why do we expect the ratio to tend to $P(B)$ if the events are independent??!

I know that $P(B|A)=P(B)$ but I want an interpretation. Moreover, the author has not yet mentioned conditional probability when he talks about independence.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

The book: Probability and Statistics - T.T. Soong

**Edit 1**: The rest of the author's argument is:

$\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}=P(B)=\frac{n_B}{n}$
,which gives: $\frac{n_{AB}}{n}=(\frac{n_{A}}{n})(\frac{n_{B}}{n})$

And the author then concludes that:

$P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$

So the author is using the argument to justify the equation above and we can't use it in the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the sample space, and for an event $E$, let $N_E$ denote the number of elements(outcomes) in the sample space where the event $E$ occurs.

Assuming uniform distribution on $X$, we have: $Pr[E]=\dfrac{n_E}{|X|}$.

Thus, $Pr[A \cap B] = \dfrac{n_{AB}}{|X|}$ and $Pr[A]=\dfrac{n_A}{|X|}$.

If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $Pr[A \cap B]=Pr[A]Pr[B]$.

That is, $Pr[B] = \dfrac{Pr[A \cap B]}{Pr[A]}=\dfrac{n_{AB}}{n_A}$.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I just added!

Comment: Independence can be defined as: $Pr[B|A]=Pr[B]$ or $Pr[A \cap B]=Pr[A]Pr[B]$. The two definitions are equivalent because: $Pr[A \cap B]=Pr[A]Pr[B|A]$. The authors' proof is only for the uniform distribution and is not the right way to go about it.